# TeamCity stopped working after server reboot?

Tags: web, iis-7, continuous-integration, windows-server-2008, teamcity

Had TeamCity setup and working perfectly. Then the server it is publishing the site to had to be rebooted and now it no longer works. There are no errors from TeamCity. No files seem to get sent to the web server. Manual publishes from Visual Studio to the web server work fine. I'm at a loss and by no means a CI pro. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you run `bin/runAll.bat start` from the TeamCity root again? (IIS)

That's what I had to do, after rebooting my Ubuntu VM (`bin/runAll.sh start`)

Note that this starts both the server and the default local build agent, if there is one.

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: For IIS (which OP was using) you can add the same .bat to execute at startup (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556.aspx). 

Note that "runAll" starts both TeamCity server as well as the default local build agent, if there is one. If you only want the server, you can use the "teamcity-server" script instead (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-StartingTeamCityserver). If you're on a Mac, you can add the daemon for server startup as well (same link).